# Azure App Services: multi-containers not starting

Tags: python, django, azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

I had my Django web app running on Azure VM then decided to move to Azure App Services using multi-container instances. However, celery seems to be breaking

Following are my docker-compose configuration and error logs for Azure App Service

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  application:
    image: expressway.azurecr.io/expressways_application:v1
    ports:
      - 80:8000
    depends_on:
      - queue
    working_dir: /data
    command: gunicorn config.wsgi:application 0.0.0.0:80
    restart: unless-stopped
  queue:
    image: expressway.azurecr.io/redis:v1
    restart: unless-stopped
  worker:
    image: expressway.azurecr.io/expressways_worker:v1
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - queue
      - application
    command: bash -c /data/docker-worker-entrypoint.sh
volumes:
  static-files:
  media-files:
   ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/site/wwwroot:/var/www/html
   ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/phpmyadmin:/var/www/phpmyadmin
```

However, the only thing that I see in my App Service logs is:

```
2022-04-08T11:47:32.913Z ERROR - multi-container unit was not started successfully
2022-04-08T11:47:32.929Z INFO  - Container logs from testoms_application_0_cb8acd23 = 2022-04-08T11:47:24.232210483Z [2022-04-08 11:47:24 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2022-04-08T11:47:24.236012528Z [2022-04-08 11:47:24 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
2022-04-08T11:47:24.236677888Z [2022-04-08 11:47:24 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2022-04-08T11:47:24.243640619Z [2022-04-08 11:47:24 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2022-04-08T11:47:24.252172692Z [2022-04-08 11:47:24 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2022-04-08T11:47:24.252216296Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-04-08T11:47:24.252223297Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2022-04-08T11:47:24.252228597Z     worker.init_process()
2022-04-08T11:47:24.252232898Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2022-04-08T11:47:24.252237698Z     self.load_wsgi()
2022-04-08T11:47:24.252241799Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2022-04-08T11:47:24.252246299Z     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2022-04-08T11:47:24.252250299Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2022-04-08T11:47:24.252254700Z     self.callable = self.load()
2022-04-08T11:47:24.252259200Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2022-04-08T11:47:24.252263501Z     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2022-04-08T11:47:24.252267501Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2022-04-08T11:47:24.252271901Z     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2022-04-08T11:47:24.252281502Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2022-04-08T11:47:24.252286203Z     __import__(module)
2022-04-08T11:47:24.253366901Z ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

Comment: depends_on option is not supported on Azure App Service, ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?tabs=debian&pivots=container-linux#unsupported-options, And to enable volumes you'll also need to go set the WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE Application settings as true.